Solving $y'=\cos x \int \cos x^2 dx$
This seems a very hard ODE that I couldn't solve.
It is from Zorich Mathematical Analysis so I guess there must be a somewhat-enlightening solution.
Though my half-attempt is here:
$$y'(x)=\cos x\int \cos x^2 dx$$
$$dy=\cos x(\int \cos x^2 dx) dx$$
$$y=\int \cos x(\int \cos x^2 dx)dx+C$$
Editted after 4 hours:
By using trigonometric series for $\cos x^2$ and $\cos x$
We get $$y(x)=\int \cos x\int \cos x^2 dx= \int \cos x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{4k+1}}{(2k)!(4k+1)} dx$$
$$y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \int x^{4k+1}\cos x dx}{(2k)!(4k+1)}$$
By adopting a power series approach again,
$$y(x)=\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j x^{2j+4k+2}}{(2k)!(2j)!(4k+1)(2j+4k+2)}$$
Now, my question is, is there a closed form for this? Or even, a better approach?

Include details of parts attempt.

@coffeemath I will do that now

If you differentiate your fourth equation,
$$\textstyle
y=\sin x (\int \cos x^2,dx)- \int \cos x\cos x^2,dx+C,,
$$
you get
$$\textstyle
y'=\cos x(\int \cos x^2,dx)+\sin x\cos x^2- \cos x\cos x^2
$$
which is not the ODE we want to solve. Another advice I give you is to use integration limits and not mess around with indefinite integrals.

@KurtG. I see. Thanks for the advice. I have also adopted power series approach, which left me with the integral $\int x^{4k+1} \cos x dx$

Do you accept answers in terms of Fresnel integrals and or Error functions? You could say $\int\cos(x^2)dx=C(x)$, so $y=\int\cos(x)C(x)dx$ and Mathematica finds a solution for this in terms of Error functions / Fresnel integrals.

@KevinDietrich Yes I do. But please provide steps.

There should be no closed form but you could write $y$ as a different series, in terms of Fresnal integral or error functions, or use some close approximations. The representation via Fresnal integral or the error function brings $y$ into a more familiar form, the series expansion further makes work "easier" and approximations possible and with approximations the possible long calculation times could be avoided.

Solution via Fresnel integrals
Using one definition of the Fresnel integrals $\operatorname{C}\left( x \right) := \int_{0}^{x} \cos\left( t^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t$ let's us simplify the equation:
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x = \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \left( \operatorname{C}\left( x \right) + \text{c}_{1} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\\
 &= \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x + \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \text{c}_{1}\, \operatorname{d}x = \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x + \text{c}_{1} \cdot \int \cos\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\\
&= \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x + \text{c}_{1} \cdot \sin\left( x \right) + \text{c}_{2}\\
\end{align*}
We can rewrite $\int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x$ to $\int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x = \int_{0}^{x} \cos\left( t \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t + \text{c}_{3}$. Using integration by parts gives us:
\begin{align*}
I_{1} &:= \int_{0}^{x} \cos\left( t \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t = \left[ \int \cos\left( t \right) \, \operatorname{d}t \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( t \right) \right]_{0}^{x} - \int_{0}^{x} \int \cos\left( t \right) \, \operatorname{d}t \cdot \operatorname{C'}\left( t \right)\, \operatorname{d}t\\
 &= \left[ \sin\left( t \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( t \right) \right]_{0}^{x} - \int_{0}^{x} \sin\left( t \right) \cdot \cos\left( t^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t = \sin\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right) - \sin\left( 0 \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( 0 \right) - \int_{0}^{x} \sin\left( t \right) \cdot \cos\left( t^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t\\
 &= \sin\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( x \right) - \int_{0}^{x} \sin\left( t \right) \cdot \cos\left( t^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t\\
\end{align*}
Integral-calculator.com can give you as step by step solution for $\int \sin\left( t \right) \cdot \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x$ (note: the site uses a different normalization then Wikipedia). Using $\sin\left( x \right) \cdot \cos\left( y \right) = \tfrac{\sin\left( x + y \right) - \sin\left( x - y \right)}{2}$ (Product-to-sum identity) let's us rewrite $\int \sin\left( t \right) \cdot \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x = \int \frac{\sin\left( x^{2} + x \right) - \sin\left( x^{2} - x \right)}{2}\, \operatorname{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \int \sin\left( x^{2} + x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x - \int \sin\left( x^{2} - x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right)$. Let $I_{2} := \int \sin\left( x^{2} + x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x$ and $I_{3} := \int \sin\left( x^{2} - x \right)\, \operatorname{d}x$, then completing the square gives us $I_{2} = \int \cos\left( \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x$ and $I_{3} = \int \sin\left( \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x$. Substituting $t_{1} := x + \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{d}t_{1} = \operatorname{d}x$ and $t_{2} := x - \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{d}t_{2} = \operatorname{d}x$ gives us $I_{2} = \int \cos\left( t_{1}^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{1}$ and $I_{3} = \int \sin\left( t_{2}^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{2}$. Using $\sin\left( x - y \right) = \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \sin\left( y \right) - \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \sin\left( y \right)$ (angle addition identity) gives us:
\begin{align*}
I_{2} &= \int \sin\left( t_{1}^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{1} = \int \left( \sin\left( t_{1}^{2} \right) \cdot \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) - \cos\left( t_{1}^{2} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{1}\\
 &= \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \int \sin\left( t_{1}^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{1} - \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( t_{1}^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{1}\\
 &= \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \operatorname{S}\left( t_{1} \right) - \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( t_{1} \right)\\
I_{3} &= \int \sin\left( t_{2}^{2} - \frac{1}{4} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{2} = \int \left( \sin\left( t_{2}^{2} \right) \cdot \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) - \cos\left( t_{2}^{2} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{2}\\
 &= \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \int \sin\left( t_{2}^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{2} - \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( t_{2}^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t_{2}\\
 &= \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \operatorname{S}\left( t_{2} \right) - \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \operatorname{C}\left( t_{2} \right)\\
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{S}\left( x \right) := \int_{0}^{x} \sin\left( t^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t$ is another Fresnal integral. Re-substituting everything gives us:
$$\fbox{$
y\left( x \right) = \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{S}\left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right) - \operatorname{S}\left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)}{2} + \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{C}\left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right) - \operatorname{C}\left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)}{2} + \left( \text{c}_{1} + \operatorname{C}\left( x \right) \right) \cdot \sin\left( x \right) + \text{c}_{2}
$}$$
You can compare the plots here on Desmos. You can write the Fresnal integrals in terms of Error functions if you like that more.
Other series solution
We know $y\left( x \right) = \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x$. The Equation is transformable into a linear ODE of second order, so we can assume two initial conditions $y\left( 0 \right) =: y_{0}$ and $y'\left( 0 \right) =: y_{1}$. The Taylor series of $y$ around $x = 0$ is definiend by $y\left( x \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{y^{\left( k \right)}\left( 0 \right)}{k!} \cdot x^{k} \right]$. Taking the derivatives:
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y'\left( x \right) &= \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\\
y''\left( x \right) &= \cos'\left( x \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x + \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\\
 &~~\vdots\\
y^{\left( k \right)}\left( x \right) &= \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{k}\left[ \binom{k}{g} \cdot \cos^{\left( k - g \right)}\left( x \right) \cdot \operatorname{D}_{x}^{g}\left[ \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right] \right]\\
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{D}_{x}^{g} := \frac{\operatorname{d}^{g}}{\operatorname{d}x^{g}}$. You can that formula by induction or by using the general Leibniz rule. It's trivial that $\operatorname{D}_{x}^{g}\left[ \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x \right] = \operatorname{D}_{x}^{g - 1}\left[ \cos\left( x^{2} \right) \right]$ and by using Faà di Bruno's formula we get ($f\left( x \right) := x^{2}$):
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D}_{x}^{g - 1}\left[ \cos\left( x^{2} \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{g - 1}\left[ \cos^{\left( n \right)}\left( f\left( x \right) \right) \cdot \operatorname{B}_{g - 1,\, n}\left( f^{\left( 1 \right)}\left( x \right),\, f^{\left( 2 \right)}\left( x \right),\, \ldots,\, f^{\left( g - 1 - n + 1 \right)}\left( x \right) \right) \right]\\
\end{align*}
We know $f^{\left( n \right)}\left( x \right) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{\left( 2 - n \right)!} \cdot x^{2 - n},\, &\text{for } n \leq 2\\ 0,\, &\text{for } n > 2\\ \end{cases}$ (you can see the proof here) and $\cos^{\left( n \right)}\left( x \right) = \cos\left( x + \frac{n}{2} \cdot \pi \right)$ which is also discused here. So (for $k \geq 2$):
\begin{align*}
y^{\left( k \right)}\left( x \right) &= \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{k}\left[ \binom{k}{g} \cdot \cos\left( x + \frac{k - g}{2} \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{g - 1}\left[ \cos\left( x^{2} + \frac{k - g}{2} \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \operatorname{B}_{g - 1,\, n}\left( 2 \cdot x,\, 2,\, \ldots,\, 0 \right) \right] \right]\\
y^{\left( k \right)}\left( 0 \right) &= \sum\limits_{g = 0}^{k}\left[ \binom{k}{g} \cdot \cos\left( \frac{k - g}{2} \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{g - 1}\left[ \cos\left( \frac{n}{2} \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \operatorname{B}_{g - 1,\, n}\left( 0,\, 2,\, \ldots,\, 0 \right) \right] \right]\\
\end{align*}
Approximation
We can say $\int_{0}^{x} \cos\left( t^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}t \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}} + \frac{\sin\left( x^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot x} \wedge x \geq 1$ (see formula $11$ here). It follows $y\left( x \right) = \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \int \cos\left( x^{2} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x\, \operatorname{d}x \approx \int \cos\left( x \right) \cdot \left( \text{c}_{1} + \frac{\sin\left( x^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot x} \right)\, \operatorname{d}x = \text{c}_{1} \cdot \sin\left( x \right) + \int \frac{\cos\left( x \right) \cdot \sin\left( x^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot x}\, \operatorname{d}x$. We could use this for numeric integration. We could also rewrite the solution in terms of Fresnal integrals (if we use formula $12$ too) to:
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &\approx \cos\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \frac{\frac{\cos\left( \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)} - \frac{\cos\left( \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)}}{2} + \sin\left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \frac{\frac{\sin\left( \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)} - \frac{\sin\left( \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right)}}{2} + \left( \text{c}_{1} + \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}} + \frac{\sin\left( x^{2} \right)}{\sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot x} \right) \cdot \sin\left( x \right) + \text{c}_{2}\\
\end{align*}
This is a little plot for this approximation ($c_{1} := 0.1 \wedge c_{2} := 0$): The red line is the Solution via Fresnel integrals minus it's value at zero and the blue line is the approximation.

You can check it here on Desmos.

Mathematica:
$$\frac{1}{8} \sqrt[4]{-1} e^{-\frac{i}{4}} \sqrt{\pi } \left(-e^{\frac{i}{2}}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{-1} (1-2
   x)\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{-1} (2 x+1)\right)\right)-i
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{3/4} (1-2
   x)\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{3/4} (2
   x+1)\right)\right)\right)+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x\right)
   \sin (x)+c_1$$

Zorich Mathematical Analysis can be downloaded
p. 369
Example 5. Suppose we need to compute the integral
$$ \int \sin(x^2) dx$$
for example within $10^{-2}$.
We know that the primitive $\int \sin(x^2) dx$ (the Fresnel integral) cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, so that it is impossible to use the Newton-Leibniz formula here in the traditional sense.
It would be nice, not to obscure a source by irregular mathematical notations and exchange cos for sin.

Note that it's the integral $\int \cos x^2 dx$, not $\int \cos^2 x dx$

Not by standard notation.  Complex arguments need brackets,  just for clarity.  The powers of trigonometric functions  nottaion came from ancient times, when they  were considered algebraic objects representing lenghts. Can't find the example in Zorich I.  Integrals of $\cos (x ^2)$ are Fresnel integrals.

@RolandF This is exactly Fresnel Integral. It was orginally $C(x)=\int \cos x^2dx$, which has a separate exercise deducing the primitive of it.

May be, but then its a Fresnel integral and not an exercise.  The simple cos  x  in front does not make any sense.   From Zorich I it*s not.
